# Copy multiple mongodb collections from one db to another while having the new copied collections renamed

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a list of collections that I want to move to another database.

This is possible with `mongodump` and `mongosrestore`, but I haven't figured out how I can rename the collections afterwards.

This is pretty much the scenario:

I have a list of mongo collections in database `A`.
The collections are in a `Prefix+CollectionName` format. Eg `DEV_MyColl`

I need to copy a bunch of such collections to database `B`, with the `Prefix` removed.
So database 'B' should have `MyColl`. meaning the `Prefix` was stripped out

So far, I can only copy them across databases with this script

```
#!/bin/bash

PFX=$1
SOURCE=$2
DESTINATION=$3
ROOT_CERT=$4
KEY_FILE=$5

LIST="matrix message_bad_log retailer_future_log retailer_log"
#LIST="tempusage tempcustusage usagecost usage"

for collection in $LIST; do

  mongodump --ssl --sslCAFile $ROOT_CERT --sslPEMKeyFile $KEY_FILE -d $SOURCE -c ${PFX}_${collection} --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 mongodb://localhost:30000


  if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "error dumping data"
    exit 1
  fi

done

mongorestore --ssl --sslCAFile $ROOT_CERT --sslPEMKeyFile $KEY_FILE -d $DESTINATION --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 dump/${SOURCE} mongodb://localhost:30000

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
  echo "error restoring data"
  exit 1
fi
```

An option I tried was to use the mongo command `db.coll.renameCollection`

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(
  function(coll){
    print(coll.substring(3))
    //db.coll.renameCollection(coll.substring(3))
  }
)
```

But this doesn't seem to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If that is a constant prefix, you could use the nsFrom and nsTo options to mongorestore, like:

```
--nsFrom "${SOURCE}.DEV_*" --nsTo "${DESTINATION}.*"
```

Comment: This doesn't help in stripping the prefix from new collections getting restored into the destination database.

So I dump such collections `${PFX}_${collection}` from database `$SOURCE`.

And I want to restore to `${DESTINATION}` collections with the `${PFX}_`  gone, so just `${collection}`.

Comment: I've stumbled upon such command - 
```$ echo "DEV_matrix" | cut -c5-``` Which outputs: 
```matrix```.
Will it be possible to utilize it here somehow?

Comment: --nsFrom "${SOURCE}.${PFX}_\*" --nsTo "${DESTINATION}.*" will strip the prefix.